# How to read a string followed by an integer..?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. 
How can I retrieve the integer value which is present after a string value 
For Example,

```
5
Hello World! 
5545
```

Each of the values are present in a new line. 
How to store the value 5545 , 5 as integer and "Hello World!" as String. Moreover the number of digits may vary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We don't do homework (if it is...). We only try to solve issues. Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Have you read [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/toc/index.html)? Great guide...

Answer (score 1):

May be that helps you.

```
result = []
with open('file_name.txt','r') as f:
for line in f:
    try:
        result.append(int(line))
    except ValueError:
        result.append(line)
```

The idea is to try to convert everything to `int`, if it raises a `ValueError`, keep it as a `string`.